# Publishing IOMedia without underlying IOBlockStorageDevice

Tags: macos, kernel, iokit, kernel-extension

**My question in a nutshell:**

Is it an acceptable/common practice for KEXT to publish an IOMedia object that does not have an IOBlockStorageDevice in its providers stack?

**Background:**

I am writing a kext that will provide some kind of virtual device to the userspace.
Currently I have a driver that matches on IOResources, then creates an object of class derived from IOMedia and attaches it to 'this'. After this media object is published, standard IOMediaBSDClient attaches to it and creates a node in /dev/.

First tests passed well, I could successfully open the created device and read data from it, but when I tried to mount it using native FS drivers, I stumbled into a problem. Device was mounted succcessfully and mountpoint was browsable, but some short time after this the kernel panicked because of a segfault deep inside vfs code.

After long debugging I found out the roots of the problem:

1. IOMediaBSDClient implements DKIOCGETTHROTTLEMASK ioctl by iterating through IOBlockStorageDevice objects in Media parents, then iterating by all Media objects that are provided by these devices and combining their BSD Unit numbers into a bitmask. Since my Media does not have any IOBlockStorageDevice parents, the resulting mask is 0.
2. The value returned by this ioctl is used by vfs_init_io_attributes() to fill mnt_throttle_mask field of mp struct corresponding to my mount.
3. Right after this, mnt_throttle_mask is converted to mnt_devbsdunit by means of calculating trailing zeros in it. Since in my case mnt_throttle_mask is 0, mnt_devbsdunit becomes 64.
4. mnt_devbsdunit is used by spec_strategy(and some other functions dealing with throttling) as an element number in _throttle_io_info, which is an array of LOWPRI_MAX_NUM_DEV elements and LOWPRI_MAX_NUM_DEV is equal to 64.
   Obviously, accessing 64 element of _throttle_io_info trashes the data located just after it, which in my case is speclisth array.

At the moment, I see 2 ways to fix this in my code:
1. Implement a class derived from IOMediaBSDClient that will handle DKIOCGETTHROTTLEMASK ioctl corrrectly.
2. Rewrite the code to publish a IOBlockStorageDevice object, and let standard IOBlockStorageDriver to publish the Media object.

Personally, I like the first solution better, but the problem that I encountered seems rather hardcore and I can't get rid of thoughts that I am doing something fundamentally wrong.

I would like to avoid problems like this in future, hence I am asking this question.

EDIT: this is true at least for OS X 10.8.3 and 10.8.5 . I didn't test this on other releases yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go with a `IOBlockStorageDevice` subclass. I've written a few drivers this way, and have never run into any problems. Direct IOStorage/IOMedia drivers are good for "filter" drivers (logical volume management, RAID, encryption, etc. - anything that sits atop "real" block devices) but as you've found, some areas of the OS expect an `IOBlockStorageDriver`/`IOBlockStorageDevice` foundation.

Converting from `IOStorage` to `IOBlockStorageDevice` is pretty straightforward: method names are pretty much prefixed with "do" or "report" and are almost exactly the same semantically otherwise. It'll probably save you some hassle in the long run. Don't create the IOBlockStorageDriver object yourself - the I/O Kit matching will create it for you as soon as you call `registerService()` on your `IOBlockStorageDevice` subclass instance.

There are some examples floating around, including a really simple one in the book [OS X and iOS[sic] Kernel Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430235365) - even if you don't have the book, you can get the example code [here](http://www.apress.com/apple-mac/objective-c/9781430235361) - chapter 14.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I converted code to IOBlockStorageDevice subclass and now it works fine.
Anyway, it seems like the only option in this case, because after some investigation I found out that one can't simply reimplement DKIOCGETTHROTTLEMASK ioctl in IOMediaBSDClient, since it is handled directly in dkioctl function.

Comment: Glad you got it all sorted out! I wasn't previously aware of the issue with DKIOCGETTHROTTLEMASK, you learn something new every day. :-)